# from requests_html import ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html'

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, instagram-api, python-requests-html

```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt031.png
instagram.py  LICENSE  Pipfile       README.md
                                                                            
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Music/Instagram]
└─$ python3 instagram.py lory.nar09 password.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Music/Instagram/instagram.py", line 10, in <module>
    from lib.proxy_manager import ProxyManager
  File "/home/kali/Music/Instagram/lib/proxy_manager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html'
                                                                            
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Music/Instagram]
└─$ password.txt3 install requests-html         
password.txt3: command not found
                                                                            
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Music/Instagram]
└─$ install requests-html              
install: missing destination file operand after 'requests-html'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

how do i solve? I would like to try the instagram dictionary attack only as a test but I can't since I get this error, how do I solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command with pip (you could also just run `pip install requests-html` without the `python3 -m` part, but doing so would not let you be sure of which Python you have installed `requests-html` to in case you have multiple on your system).

```sh
python3 -m pip install requests-html
```

Not sure what you're trying with `install requests-html`. [Pip](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/) is the common way to go.

Comment: now that requests_html notice no longer comes out. but now I get this warning, can you tell me how I can do it?                                                                                                          
    usage: instagram.py [-h] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSLIST] [-px PROXYLIST]
                    [--prune PRUNE] [--stats] [-nc] [-m MODE]
instagram.py: error: unrecognized arguments: lory.nar09 password.txt

Comment: Nope, I'm not familiar with the Instagram API. Sorry. I would suggest that you search for help or make a separate post for that, as it is technically a separate question. If your `requests_html` problem is sorted out, please accept this answer for future users' sake.